# Drag and Drop - JavaScript ou JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html5

Bom dia...
Fui desafiado a converter uma aplicação C# Desktop para Web, porém não tenho conhecimento algum de ASP.NET, nem JScript ou JQuery.
E dentre os componentes que preciso adaptar está um DRAGDROPTEXT. É uma SPAN dentro de uma DIV que é capaz de ser arrastável até outra DIV. Fiz isso através de JavaScript e HTML5. A internet está cheia de exemplos básicos para isso.
Até aqui nada de mais.

Para ilustrar o que preciso implementar vou descrever parte do cenário:

Na tela existem várias DIVS, de depois tipos: Arrastar e Recipiente, os nomes são trazidos de um banco e nesse momento eu personalizei o nome da DIV na aplicação WEB, exemplo: ArrastarDRAGDROPTEXT2354, RecipienteDRAGDROPTEXT2354, .... onde o número final é um ID no banco.
A tela é composta por exercícios de completar lacunas de um referido curso, logo terão alguns pares de DIV (arrastar e recipiente). 
Nessa tela em questão, há 5 pares desses DIVS.

O que preciso implementar e não consigo: 
Se o usuário ao término das ações de drag and drop perceber que uma resposta está errada e quiser refazer o dragdrop o programa deveria permitir que ao arrastar a DIV que já está no campo de resposta fosse possível ao usuário soltar o clique do mouse em qualquer área da tela e se nessa área da tela que foi solto o mouse não for uma DIV então a DIV que acabou de ser solta deverá voltar a sua posição de início.
Note que início aqui seria a situação ANTES da DIV ter sido arrastada pela primeira vez.

Por favor, lembrem-se não tenho conhecimento algum de JQUERY, JScript ou ASP.Net.

Agradeço a colaboração!

Comment: apesar de fazer pouca diferença, mas como está a iniciar com ASP.NET e JavaScript, gostaria de saber se está utilizando MVC ou WebForms? Isto não vai alterar o JavaScript, porem a forma de inseri-lo na pagina.

Comment: No caso WebForms.

Comment: infelizmente não estou com tempo para realizar toda a implementação. mas você pode dá uma olhada nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50690/como-mover-um-elemento-at%C3%A9-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-outro-com-jquery/50733#50733, que possui uma implementação para drag & drop.

Comment: Leandro, já que está iniciando com WebForms, te aconselho a dá uma lida no seguinte material: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx.
Especialmente na forma como utilizar bundle, optimization e cdn. Digo isto pq é comum nós devs apenas arrastamos os scripts para a pagina, e isto não é aconselhavel para aplicações WebForms.

Comment: A implementação padrão e básica para Drag and Drop em JScript é:    function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));      
        }

Comment: Essa ajuda sobre como comentar usando codigo, aqui do site, não ajudou nada :/

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma vista de olhos [neste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/40/). Terás que:

1. modificar a forma como é despoletado o reset - em vez de ser ao carregar no botão reset, é quando largares um item no vazio;
2. em vez de fazer reset a todos os items, é só ao que for largado no vazio.